# how to associate checkbox used in view to update a field in a RoR table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a new field called "Reviewed" in one of my tables called "Posts".
Everytime someone checkmarks prior to their post, I want it to be Reviewed for approval prior to display.

The "Reviewed" field in the table is defaulted to True. 
Here's the schema.db

```
create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.text      "content"
    t.integer   "user_id"
    t.timestamp "created_at",                        :null => false
    t.timestamp "updated_at",                        :null => false
    t.boolean   "reviewed",        :default => true
```

Here's the code in the view that I'm using for the checkmark

```
<%= label_tag(:post_reviewed, "Review this post") %>
<%= check_box_tag(:post_reviewed) %>
```

I want it so that every time this checkbox is checked, the reviewed field is set to False so that the post is not displayed until I review it and update it to True. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have something like this in your view:

```
<%= form_for :post do |f| %>
..
<% end %>
```

So, just try to add to it:

```
<%= f.check_box :reviewed %>
```

That should automatically associate it to the desired object.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks this worked in making the post reviewed field to be either true or false. But it looks like the checkbox defaults to being "checked" every time I open the page. Is that simply because of :default=>true in the database? And if I only want to display posts that have been approved in the view (basically all posts where reviewed => true), what's the best way to do that?

Comment: I think the best way to accomplish that is creating a `scope` in your `Post` model.

And yes, the behaviour is because you have `:default => true`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your doing everything backwards. If you want to go down that route, than you should change it to `review` and only display items scoped to `where(review: false)`. That way, if a user wants a post to be reviewed prior to publishing, then they would check the checkbox.

I don't know what the process is, but if all posts MUST be reviewed, why not change the field to `reviewed_at` and make it a datetime. Then you only show posts `where('reviewed_at IS NOT NULL')`. This is similar to `deleted_at` or `published_at`.

I hope this helps.